# How to install afpfs-ng in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, dpkg, 32-bit, file-sharing

After downloading and running `sudo dpkg --install afpfs-ng_0.8.1-1_i386.deb` I get

```
Selecting previously unselected package afpfs-ng:i386.
(Reading database ... 120690 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack afpfs-ng_0.8.1-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking afpfs-ng:i386 (0.8.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of afpfs-ng:i386:
 afpfs-ng:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.6-1).
 afpfs-ng:i386 depends on libfuse2 (>= 2.6).
 afpfs-ng:i386 depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.2.2).
 afpfs-ng:i386 depends on libncurses5 (>= 5.6).
 afpfs-ng:i386 depends on libreadline5 (>= 5.2).

dpkg: error processing package afpfs-ng:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 afpfs-ng:i386
```

I have also executed `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` to get so far.

Is there a way to install it anyway? Or do I need a 64bit-Version from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to install the 64-bit package using packages [from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://repology.org/project/afpfs-ng/versions).

To download and install the packages use commands below:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/afpfs-ng
cd ~/Downloads/afpfs-ng
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/readline6/libreadline6_6.3-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.6_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/afpfs-ng/libafpclient0_0.8.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/multiarch-support_2.19-0ubuntu6.15_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/afpfs-ng/afpfs-ng-utils_0.8.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/afpfs-ng/afpfs-ng_0.8.1-5ubuntu1_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./afpfs-ng_0.8.1-5ubuntu1_all.deb ./afpfs-ng-utils_0.8.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libafpclient0_0.8.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libreadline6_6.3-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./multiarch-support_2.19-0ubuntu6.15_amd64.deb ./libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.6_amd64.deb
```

Then use its executables:

- `/usr/bin/afpcmd`
- `/usr/bin/afpgetstatus`
- `/usr/bin/afpfsd`
- `/usr/bin/mount_afp`
- `/usr/bin/afp_client`

Comment: This solution will lead to encountering this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/afpfs-ng/+bug/962718

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu got rid of `afpfs-ng`. You may use `afpfs-ng` package from another disto. I put deb-package from ArchLinux into Github repo https://github.com/maxx27/afpfs-ng-deb

So you may use it something like this:

```sh
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maxx27/afpfs-ng-deb/main/afpfs-ng.deb
sudo apt install ./afpfs-ng.deb
sudo mkdir -p /media/airport
sudo mount_afp afp://myuser:mypass@mycapsule/Data /media/airport
sudo ls /media/airport
sudo umount /media/airport
```